# Inject uint16_t value into uint8_t array using pointers?

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert a uint16_t value into a uint8_t array using pointers. I would think below would work, but haven't been able to do it. Any clues as to what the problem is?

```
uint8_t myarray[10];
uint16_t value = 10000;
uint16_t * myptr = (uint16_t *)(myarray+2);
*myptr = value;
```

I know I can do it like so, but why doesn't above work?

```
uint8_t myarray[10];
uint16_t value = 10000;
uint8_t * myptr = (myarray+2);
uint8_t * myptr2 =(myarray+3);
*myptr = value>>8;
*myptr2 =value;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the first code ?

Comment: Without looking too much at the specifics, seems you're "aliasing" so that two different types are living in the same memory.  You can only "alias" lvalues if they are of "compatible types" (*compatible types differ only by the addition of any combination of signed, unsigned, or volatile*)  Some light reading on this subject: http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html

Answer (score 3):

The second version writes the most significant byte (with value 39) to `myarray[2]`, and the least significant (with value 16) to `myarray[3]`.

The first version will write the two bytes in an order determined by the [*endianness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your computer. Most modern computers are *little-endian*, meaning that the least significant byte of a multi-byte integer value comes first in memory - so this version will write the two bytes in the opposite order to the other version.

I'm assuming that that's the problem you're seeing; if it's something else, then please be more specific than "haven't been able to do it".

Also, the first version technically has undefined behaviour, and might do something completely unexpected on a sufficiently exotic computer. I suggest that you stick to well-defined code like the second version; only use dubious optimisations if profiling reveals both that the well-defined code is too slow, and that the dodgy pointer-aliasing code is faster. I would also suggest using `reinterpret_cast` rather than the evil C-style cast; it wouldn't change the behaviour, but it would be easier to see that there's something wonky going on.

Comment: I tried modifying the code as such, it seems to work. Would there be any issues with this? 

    uint8_t myarray[10];
    uint16_t value = 10000;
    void * ptr = &myarray;
    uint16_t * myptr = (((uint16_t *)ptr)+2);
    *myptr = value>>8|value<<8;

Comment: @user1142327: It's relying on undefined behaviour, and isn't portable. As I said, you should only use dodgy optimisations like that if you've established that (a) the well-defined version isn't fast enough, and (b) the dodgy version is indeed faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
uint8_t * value_data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&value); // cast to `(unsigned) char*` is allowed by standard
myarray[0] = value_data[0];
myarray[1] = value_data[1];
```